# How to share states between windows of a browser without using a server

Tags: javascript

Assuming that there is a website and the user can spin up several windows opening the same website. How do I ensure that the changes user makes in one window gets reflected in all other windows accordingly? Can anyon provide some leads on any potential concepts that may be leverage here?

One such example may be the tredning ["Entangled" by Bjorn Staal](https://twitter.com/_nonfigurativ_/status/1727322594570027343)

Comment: [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API)?

Comment: @mandy8055 nah - there's no code in the question, so why would I write code for the OP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the "storage" event that notifies you when another tab has modified localStorage.
It is important to note that it only runs on the tab that has not modified localStorage.

To test, do the following:

1. Open two tabs on a website (I will use https://stackoverflow.com/)
2. In the first tab, enter this code in the console to monitor localStorage:

   ```
   window.addEventListener("storage", event => {
     console.log(event)
   })
   ```
3. In the second tab, add some value to localStorage:

   ```
   localStorage.setItem("a", 1)
   ```
4. Go back to the console in the first tab and you will see the event, something like this:

   ```
   {
     type: "storage"
     url: "https://stackoverflow.com/"
     key: "a"
     newValue: "1"
     oldValue: null
     ...
   }
   ```
5. Obviously this only works in one browser and on the same user.

Answer (score 0):

Using localStorage to store the data you need to share ,because the localStorage is always the same in the same domain name